# Is each prime ideal in a quadratic field of norm $p$ or $p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know that in a quadratic field  $K $ there is a splitting behavior for primes $p$.

$p$ splits  in $K$ if $p\mathcal{O_K}=\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{p'},$ for two prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\neq\mathfrak{p'} $ of norm $p$.

$p$ is inert in $K$ if $p \mathcal{O_K}$ is a prime ideal  in $\mathcal{O_K} $ of norm $p^2$.

$p$ is ramified in $K$ if $p \mathcal{O_K}=\mathfrak{p}^2$ for some ideal of norm $p$.

Is every  prime ideal in $\mathcal{O_K}$  of this form?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is question of a quadratic extension of number fields, $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois, and a prime $p\in \Bbb Z=\mathcal O_{\Bbb Q}$ splits into $(P_1 P_2 \dots P_r )^e$ in $\mathcal O_K$ where the $P_i$ are distinct primes, all having the same inertial degree $f$
 over $p$. Moreover $ref = [K : \Bbb Q ]=2$.

You listed all the possible splitting behaviours of $p\mathcal O_K$.

Now taking a random prime ideal $P\in \mathcal O_K$, it is not always of the form $p\mathcal O_K$ for a prime $p\in \Bbb Z$, as an example:

Take $K=\Bbb Q(i)$, and $P=(1-2i)$ is a prime of $\mathcal O_K$ lying over $5=(1-2i)(1+2i)$. But $P$ is not of the form $p\mathcal O_K$ for $p\in \Bbb  Z$ prime.

Comment: thanks for the help. I just wanted to know whether each prime ideal in $\mathcal{O_K}$ is of the form $p\mathcal{O_K}$.

Comment: You are welcome.  Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal in $O_K$, the ring of integers of a quadratic number field $K$. It can be shown that $\mathfrak p \cap \Bbb Z = p\Bbb Z$, where $p\in \Bbb Z$ is a prime number. So, $p \in \mathfrak p$, giving $pO_K = (p) \subset \mathfrak p$. Therefore, $\mathfrak p$ divides $pO_K$. Write $pO_K = \mathfrak p \mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a \subset O_K$. Taking norms on both sides,
$$p^2 = N(pO_K) = N(\mathfrak p) N(\mathfrak a)$$
which means $N(\mathfrak p)$ divides $p^2$. As a result, $N(\mathfrak p)$ can only be $p$ or $p^2$.